# Deleting duplicate records using SQL code, searching 3 columns, but showing all columns

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database that I am trying to delete the duplicate records (there is no way to stop these as its from an excel spread sheet that has over 70,000 records)

I have created a couple of queries using SQL to get the total number to around 1400 records, however there are still duplicates where a customer has entered the postcode for instance with and then again without a space inbetween.

What I was hoping for, is to do a SQL query to delete all duplicate records searching on the First Name, Surname and postcode, however I need it to show the results with all columns (Title, First Name, Surname, Address, Address2, Town/City, County, Postcode)

I hope this makes sense to someone as I have been searching everywhere for an answer, but nothing really makes sense as this is the first time I have started using SQL coding so I am a complete novice when it comes to this.

I am currently using Microsoft Access 2010

Comment: Please enter your database schema and will you use sql server to delete records?

Comment: Also didnt understood what do you mean by delete duplicate records and show result with all columns?

Comment: Well how I want it to work is by SQL searching 3 fields for duplicates, the First name, Surname and Postcode.

Comment: however in the results i want to be able to see the rest of the columns. I have tried myself but it doesn't work (see below)

Comment: SELECT [First Name], Surname, Postcode, Count (ID)
From SurnameSearch
GROUP BY Title, [First Name], Surname, Address, Address2, Town/City, County, Postcode
HAVING Count (Surname, Postcode) >1

Comment: what? I cant see anything

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: Also why have you grouped by Address, Address2, Town/City, County. They are not in your select list so should not be in your group by clause

Answer (score 1):

In MS Access, there are wizards, for example, the find duplicates wizard.

The SQL from the steps below is:

```
SELECT Table1.[AText], Table1.[ADate], Table1.[ANumber]
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.[AText]) In (SELECT [AText] 
   FROM [Table1] As Tmp GROUP BY [AText] HAVING Count(*)>1 )))
ORDER BY Table1.[AText];
```

If you are stuck, the query wizards are very helpful.

**Select query type**

[image: Select query type]

**Select the table**

[image: Select the table]

**Select the field or fields for which you want to find duplicates**

[image: Select the field or fields for which you want to find duplicates]

**Select any additional fields**

[image: **Select any additional fields**]

**The query in design view**

[image: The query in design view]